# AWS Lambda - serverless - try/catch?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

My setup looks like:

```
export const someAWSLambaJob: AWSLambda.Handler<ScheduledEvent> = async () => {
    try {
        await loadSome();
        await loadSomeMore();
        console.log('success');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('failure');
        await axios.post(url, `something went wrong ${e.message}`);
    }
};
```

Problem is: When `loadSome()`or `loadSomeMore()` throw an error, it seem like in AWS Lambda execution it doesn't even and up in the catch here. The job is immediately cancelled. Also, when putting some `console.log()` in there, it doesn't show up which it should viewing the cloudLogs on the dashboard.

Comment: Try catch works exactly the same as anywhere else. Does the lambda have permission to write logs to cloudwatch?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the 'job' is cancelled (other than the lack of CloudWatch Logs, which the earlier comment on [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) addresses)?

Comment: In my case the success log is shown in cloudWatch, the failure one doesn't. That's my evidence it's really not coming there. Updated the code snippet

Comment: Is there an END and REPORT log? What does the REPORT log show? Did the Lambda function time out?

Comment: yes, there's an END & REPORT. There's no task timed out message in the REPORT. My average job time is ~25000ms and my timeout configured on the job is 60s.

Comment: your loadSome or loadSomeMore probably has unhandled rejections?